# How can a REST API integration handle detecting what environment it is being loaded in?

Tags: rest-api, oauth

I maintain a WordPress plugin that is based on a REST API integration. When a user installs the plugin, they create a custom app in Salesforce, save the credentials in WordPress, and run through an OAuth process, after which the tokens are saved into the WordPress database. It is generally the case that each integration is represented by a different application in Salesforce. So there are different consumer keys/secrets/callback URLs stored in each WordPress database.

This setup works fine until someone imports a database from one environment to another. For example, if you download a site's production database and run it locally, or on a staging server. In these cases the integration will run into errors because the production app's credentials are still stored from that environment's OAuth process.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to address this. Ideally, it would be nice if I could automatically detect that the OAuth situation had changed and refresh the whole thing without the user having to do anything. But alternatively, I think it would be better than the current situation where nothing happens if I were able to notify them that they have to re-authenticate, and then they could go through the OAuth process again.

When I look at what is stored in the WordPress database, I do see the Salesforce environment (https://sandboxname.domain.salesforce.com for example) in various places, but I don't see a way to basically tell WordPress that it should be looking for a different one. I also don't see anywhere that Salesforce is checking to see what URL WordPress is using. This makes sense, but it leaves me unclear how to tell the system that its environment has changed.

Comment: Which env it is connecting to and if it is appropriate for your wordpress instance is an external to salesforce knowledge and must be managed as config.

Comment: This is partly accurate. Things like consumer key, consumer secret, callback URL can and should be stored in the config. But once the OAuth process has been completed, the instance-identifying data that is returned from Salesforce cannot be stored in the config.

Comment: with env it is connecting to, I meant, initial oauth init urls like https://test.salesforce.com or https://login.salesforce.com. Of course the individual org instance urls (for ex., https://company.my.salesforce.com) etc., should be consumed off of the login response.

Comment: That's what my question is about. Once Oauth has already happened, that is, after the login response exists. I'm confused about the relevance of these comments; is my question unclear?

Comment: If you try to use refresh/access token that were created in one env (prod in your case) against stage (after copy in your case), sfdc will thrown an error that session is invalid or invalid refresh token. You can catch those errors and prompt user to reauth again.

Comment: At least in my testing over the years this doesn't work immediately, I've found that it only works after a period of time when the refresh token expires. Hence the question.